# There is no plus button when I click "show tab bar"

Tags: macos, web, cocoa, tabs

I'm working on a web browser app for mac. I was playing with the test app then I saw this option...

[image]

When I clicked on that, I saw this...

[image]

**But there was no plus button.** Is there any way I can show the plus button in the tab?

Please don't send me the link to the Apple documentation because it doesn't give the exact code.

BTW, this is not a document based app

Comment: That is a really good question

Comment: Note that you can delete your topic if desired.  Replacing it with gibberish doesn't do anything useful, since the edit history can still be viewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an app developed by Apple Inc. You can download it. In this app, you can add tabs. So change the name of this app and you're all set

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/developing_a_document-based_app

Wish you best of luck on making a web browser